# Change Image when mouse rollsover

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, p5.js

Im coding in P5. I have two images on my page. Im trying to code it to the affect that when the mouse is to the left of the image it changes to the other image. This is the specific: next we will create a hover over effect, in which the images changes when the mouse passes over it.

We will use 2 images, img1 and img2 and switch between the two when the mouse passes over them. We will use variables imageX and imageY for the x and y positions of the top left of the image.

We need an if statement that looks a bit like this:

```
if(XXX){
   image(img2, imageX, imageY);
} else {
   image(img1, imageX, imageY);
}
```

where XXX is a condition that we need to test. We need to get a condition that corresponds to the mouse going over the image.

This is a bit like colliding a ball with the sides of the screen. We need to check each side in turn. Let's start with the left hand side. This is the minimum x value of the image, which corresponds to our imageX variable. To be on our image the mouseX has to be more than imageX.

If you do it correctly the image will now change whenever the mouse is to the right of the left hand side of the image.

I was able to do it by writing a function but I cant complete the task with if statements which is what they want in the book.

This is the code I have:

```
var img1;
var img2;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  img1 = loadImage("assets/Slammer.jpg");
  img2 = loadImage("assets/rollercoaster.jpg")

}

function draw() {
  image(img1, 100, 100);
  image(img2, 300, 300);
}

  if mouseX > img2{
    image(img2, imageX, imageY);
  } else {
    image(img1, imageY, imageY);
  }
```

Can anyone see what Im doing wrong here and help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Trying to make an image trigger a function - p5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70059507/trying-to-make-an-image-trigger-a-function-p5-js/74734992#)

Answer (score 0):

This section of code doesn't make a ton of sense:

```
function draw() {
  image(img1, 100, 100);
  image(img2, 300, 300);
}

  if mouseX > img2{
    image(img2, imageX, imageY);
  } else {
    image(img1, imageY, imageY);
  }
```

In your `draw()` function, you're displaying both of the images. But the `if` statement is **outside** the `draw()` function, so it only happens once when your code is first loaded (which I would bet causes an error because you can't call the `image()` function until after `setup()` is called).

In any case, even if you moved that code inside the `draw()` function, you're comparing `mouseX` (which is a number) to `img2` (which is an image). What do you expect that comparison to do? How can a number be greater than an image?

It sounds like you want to compare the image's position to the mouse position. Here's an example that draws black if the mouse is on the left and white if the mouse is on the right:

```
function draw(){
   if(mouseX < width/2){
      background(0);
   }
   else{
      background(255);
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, yes I basically want the image to change to the second one when the mouse is on the left of either picture. The book isn't written especially well so its quite hard to understand what it wants you to do most of the time. How do I use that code you writ to change the images?

Comment: @YusufBismillah That depends on exactly what you want them to change to. Please try something and post an updated [mcve] in a new question post if you get stuck.

Comment: Hi Kevin, got it working using a tutorial off YouTube. Thanks for the help though.