# Trying to make an image trigger a function on click - p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm working on a project for an art class with an interactive canvas. My goal is to make little animals play noises and "move" when they are either clicked on. I'm attempting to do this without creating a class, as I cannot use an image in a class for some reason. I'm trying to do this as easily as possible.

What I mean by "move", is I am trying to make an image of the background appear over them with the animal in a different pose. The default background is of the landscape with the animal, then when the mouse is on them a different image is displayed with the animal in a different pose.

TLDR: need function that when mouse is over a certain area it'll display an image and play a sound.

```
function preload() {
  birdsSound = loadSound("sounds/birds.mp3");
  backgrnd = loadImage("images/backgrnd.png");
  birdsImage = loadImage("images/birds.png");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000, 750);
  birdsImage.mouseOver(birdsFUNC);

}

function draw() {
  image(backgrnd,0,0);

}


function birdsFUNC() {
    birdsSound.play();
    image(birdsImage,0,0);
}
```

Also I should add that I am *very* new to coding in anything beyond MATLAB, so p5 is completely new. Explain it to me like I'm five.

Answer (score 0):

In p5.js an Image ([`p5.Image`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image) object created with `loadImage()`), is not a graphical element with a position within the canvas. It is just the pixel data for the image that can be drawn to the canvas. Images, and all other graphical elements in p5.js, are drawn to the canvas in [immediate mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediate_mode_(computer_graphics)), and so are also not persistent elements with a position on the canvas. In order to implement things like mouse hover or hit detection on specific graphical elements you have to implement this yourself based on the mouse position (via `mouseX` and `mouseY`), and the coordinates where you have drawn the graphical element in question. Here is a simple example:

```js
let img;
let imgHover;
let vel;
let pos;

function preload() {
    img = loadImage('https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/AnimFrame00.png');
    imgHover = loadImage('https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/AnimFrame01.png');
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    vel = p5.Vector.random2D();
    pos = createVector(random(0, width - img.width), random(0, height - img.height));
}

function draw() {
    background(200);
    
    // check if the mouse is over the image or not
    let hover =
            mouseX >= pos.x && mouseX <= pos.x + img.width &&
            mouseY >= pos.y && mouseY <= pos.y + img.height;
    
    if (hover) {
        image(imgHover, pos.x, pos.y);
    } else {
        image(img, pos.x, pos.y);
    }
    
    // Move the image
    pos.add(vel);
    if (pos.x < 0) {
        pos.x = -pos.x;
        vel.x = -vel.x;
    } else if (pos.x + img.width > width) {
        pos.x = width - (pos.x + img.width - width) - img.width;
        vel.x = -vel.x;
    }
    if (pos.y < 0) {
        pos.y = -pos.y;
        vel.y = -vel.y;
    } else if (pos.y + img.height > height) {
        pos.y = height - (pos.y + img.height - height) - img.height;
        vel.y = -vel.y;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: And if you DO want mouse events on canvas objects, you may look into PixiJS, which keeps track of your objects positions on a canvas and gives them click handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Another option than writing an image to canvas and checking coordinates is to use `createImg`, then add `mouseX` handlers to that [element](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element):

```js
let img;

function setup() {
  noLoop();
  noCanvas();
  img = createImg("https://picsum.photos/200/160", "kitten");
  img.mouseOver(() => console.log("mouse in"));
  img.mouseOut(() => console.log("mouse out"));
  img.mouseMoved(() => console.log("mouse moved"));
  img.mouseClicked(() => console.log("mouse clicked"));
  img.mouseReleased(() => console.log("mouse released"));
  img.mouseWheel(event => {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent scrolling
    console.log("mouse wheel");
  });
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```